# API not found in vercel deployment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, mern, vercel

I have deployed my web app on vercel using github. Frontend has been loaded but the api request that the frontend is making giving 404 not found. It's a MERN app by the way
Here is my vercel.json

```
{
    "buildCommand": "cd client && npm install && ./node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js build",
    "outputDirectory": "client/dist",
    "framework": "vite",
    "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "/api/(.*)",
            "destination": "/index.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const router = require('./router/router');
const setupCronJob = require('./cron');
const fs = require('fs');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());    // for reading cookies
const allowedOrigins = ['http://127.0.0.1:5173','https://cozy-stay.vercel.app'];
const corsOptions = {
    credentials: true,
    origin: allowedOrigins,
    methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE',
    allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type, Authorization, Cookie'
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 10000,
}).then(()=> {
    console.log('Connected to database')
}).catch(err=>{
    throw err;
})
setupCronJob();
app.use('/api',router);
app.listen(port);
```

Here is the directory img

[image]

Frontend has been but api not working i think i api has not been loaded. Please help me
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems what happens currently is `https://cozy-stay.vercel.app/api` path requests go to the frontend server and not to your backend server as you expect:

```
Request URL: https://cozy-stay.vercel.app/api/all-places
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 
Remote Address: 76.76.21.9:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

#### Fix 01

You can use two vercel apps for the front-end and the backend:

- cozy-stay.vercel.app
- cozy-stay-backend.vercel.app - Use this as the backend server host in the frontend app.

#### Fix 02

You can run a load balancer to send all `/api` prefixed requests to the backend and others to the frontend. IDK this supported in vercel platform.